# Webpack Babel NodeJS Error : Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to implement SSR in my node express server and react application.

After difficulties, I could get my files compiled by webpack and babel but when I try `node dist/server.js` I get this error:

```sh
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: Z:\alpha\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\defineProperty.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of Z:\alpha\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\defineProperty.js from Z:\alpha\dist\server.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename defineProperty.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from Z:\alpha\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\package.json.

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:63287:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread2.js (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:47967:99)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Module../views/web/src/lib/connector.js (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:42244:154)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Object../views/web/src/hooks/useFetch.ts (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:53066:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Object../views/web/src/hooks/index.ts (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:52993:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Object../views/web/src/components/BottomCartIcon/BottomCartIcon.tsx (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:48855:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Object../views/web/src/components/BottomCartIcon/index.ts (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:48940:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Object../views/web/src/hoc/Layout/Layout.tsx (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:52823:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:64334:42)
    at Object../views/web/src/hoc/Layout/index.tsx (Z:\alpha\dist\server.js:52940:16) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const path = require("path");

const browserConfig = {
    entry: "./views/web/src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/webpack'),
        publicPath: 'public/webpack',
        filename: "./public/webpack/bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },

            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    "style-loader",
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "css-loader",
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
                    publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, "")
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: { importLoaders: 1 }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [autoprefixer()]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: { presets: ["react-app"] }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ]
};

const serverConfig = {
    entry: "./lib/www",
    target: "node",
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist', 
        filename: "server.js",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },
    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            {
                test: /\.node$/,
                use: "node-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    "style-loader",
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "css-loader",
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
                    publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, ""),
                    emit: false
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: { presets: ["react-app", "@babel/preset-env"] }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig];
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true
    }
  }
```

`.babelrc`

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
        "@babel/transform-arrow-functions",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties"
    ],
    "sourceType": "unambiguous"
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "alpha",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=development& webpack -w & SET NODE_ENV=development & node dist/server.js",
    "production": "SET NODE_ENV=production & webpack -w & SET NODE_ENV=production & node dist/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/isomorphic-fetch": "0.0.35",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/react-content-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/react-infinite-scroll-component": "^4.2.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-select": "^3.0.15",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.3",
    "antd": "^4.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "country-state-city": "^1.0.5",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "du": "^1.0.0",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-useragent": "^1.0.15",
    "extract-zip": "^1.7.0",
    "file-type": "^14.7.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formidable": "^1.2.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "helmet": "^3.23.3",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.13.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jimp": "^0.9.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.2",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.0",
    "react-alice-carousel": "^1.19.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-checkbox-group": "^5.0.2",
    "react-content-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^5.1.3",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.0.8",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-image-zoom": "^1.3.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.5",
    "react-items-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.7.4",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.5.5",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.3.1",
    "react-query": "^2.5.14",
    "react-radio-buttons": "^1.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-modal": "^1.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "react-scroll-into-view-if-needed": "^2.1.7",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-share": "^4.2.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.11",
    "react-star-rating-component": "^1.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "sharp": "^0.25.4",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.10.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```